# Handle an event thrown in IronPython from vb.net

Tags: python, vb.net, dll, ironpython

I'm using `IronPython` to try and connect into my vb.net program.

I'm trying to get some path to have events travel between the two (not sure if this is even possible.)

What I did was create a common `DLL`, my program (`vb.net`) references it as well as the `IronPython` script, the python is then executed in my `vb.net` code.

Is this possible at all In `IronPython`? I can't find any way to pass an object of type A between them, or get them to link up via event.

Answer (score 0):

The general way of handling exceptions would require that your VB.net program should have a reference/dependency on the IronPython one. Exceptions are thrown up the call stack until they are handled. The architecture you described suggests they are peers and have no direct dependency on each other so handling those exceptions won't work in a `Catch` block as normal.

The only way I can see this working (top of my head) is if you can handle exceptions in your IronPython by sending them to a method in the common DLL that raises an event with the exception as part of the event args much like you can get an `UnhandledException` event

```
AddHandler My.Application.UnhandledException, AddressOf Foo
```

that would allow your VB code to respond to what happened in IronPython app.

Comment: I gave this a try yesterday after posting the event. I couldn't get the event to trigger one in my .net code. As far as I could tell, the event needs to belong to an object, and you can't have one object shared across the python and .net.

Comment: What do you mean you can't have objects shared? When IronPython calls a method that returns a .net Object IronPython will now have a reference to that object to use just as if it were created in .Net.

Answer (score 0):

`IronPython` uses `System.Reflection` extenisively.  It automatically imports the types and methods made available to it.

You can expose your types in a DLL class library.

After building your DLL you can import it in 'IronPython'

```
import clr    
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(r"C:\SomeFolder\SomeClassLibrary.dll")
```

You can also load DLL's and import namespaces on the fly:

```
sys.path.append(r"C:\SomeFolder")  
clr.AddReference ("SomeClassLibrary.dll") # Your Class libary
import SomeNamspace  # import SomeNamespace from your dll.
```

In your library expose your events:

```
Public Class SomeClass

    Public Event SomeEvent ....
```

You can then use them in `IronPython

```
def SomeHandleHandler(*args):
    pass

Foo.SomeEvent += SomeHandleHandler
```

To do the opposite and trigger the event using `IronPython` you simply need to add the handler in your Vb.Net code.

Here is working code:

MyIpyClass.vb in Class Libary MyClassLibary

```
Public Class MyIpyClass
    Public Event MyEvent()

    Public Sub New()
        AddHandler MyEvent, HandleMyEvent()
    End Sub

    Private Function HandleMyEvent() as MyEventEventHandler
        Console.WriteLine("Raised My Event")
        Return Nothing
    End Function


    Public Sub RaiseMyEvent()
        RaiseEvent MyEvent()
    End Sub

End Class
```

IronPython code:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
clr.AddReference("System.Drawing")
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("C:\\MyDllPath\\MyClassLibary.dll")
import MyClassLibary
from System.Windows.Forms import *
from System.Drawing import *


def mevent(*args): print("Event From IPY") # create IPython event hander for MyIpyClass.MyEvent

m = MyClassLibary.MyIpyClass() # create new instance of my class
m.MyEvent += mevent # Add IPythong Handler
m.RaiseMyEvent() # For Simplicity, Call MyIpyClass.MyEvent.RaiseEvent to raise the event



f = Form() # Create a Form to handle some events from System.Windows.Forms
f.Text = "My Form"

#defne a form click handler to print out the event args
def click(*args): print args
f.Click += click  

b = Button() # Create a button and add it to the form
b.Text = "GO"
b.Name = "GO"
b.Location = Point(10,10)

#create a button click handler that prints hellow word
def click(f, a):
    print("hello world")

#assign the button click handler
b.Click += click

#add the button to the form
f.Controls.Add(b)

#call Form.ShowDialog() - Show() blocks and will hang the form.
f.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: I got this far on my own. What I couldn't do was to get the event to be thrown by the python and handled in my VB.net code.

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked you to clarify what your issue is. If you got that far then the only thing left to do is use your objects like you would in VB. I have attached full working code.